# Number of calulations/steps in each line of an algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, big-o

I have a function here that I can see is O(N^2). However, I'm trying to figure out exactly how many steps/calculations each line uses.

```
void hi(int n){
  for (int i=1; i <= n; i++) {        //line 1
    for (int k = i; k <= n; k++) {    //line 2
      puts("hi");                     //line 3
    }
  }
}
```

For line 1, I believe it's 1+(N+1)+1.

Lines 2 and 3 are supposedly both sum(i=1 to n)(3i+2) but I don't see how. Where did this summation come from?

Answer (score 0):

Line 1 is executed 1 time. However, it executes 1 initialization, n comparisons and increments.

Line 2 is executed n times. However, it executes n initialization, n*(n+1)/2 comparisons and increments.

Line 3 is executed n*(n+1)/2 times. Due to http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/qq.02.06/jo1.html

The total number of operations is therefore 1 + 3n + 3n*(n+1)/2.

Comment: How come Line 1 is executed once??

Comment: Normally you count the for-element, not the incrementor, therefore the for is only executed 1 time for every time hi is called.

Comment: I'm supposed to include all the parts of the for loop. Would line 2 then be N*(1+(N+1)+1)?

Comment: No, it is exactly as stated. The inner-most would determine you Big-O notation, which as you stated yourself is O(n^2). The total number of operations executed is the sum of lines (1) + (n) + (n*(n+1)/2).

Comment: Right, but I think we are looking at different levels of granularity. For example, you mentioned that normally you only count the for loop as one, but in my case, I have to also include the initialization, condition test, and increment which is why I have 1+(n+1)+1.

Comment: Ok, I updated with number of operations at each step.

Answer (score 0):

The outer `for` statement is executed once ... albeit, it iterates `n` times (due to the start condition, end condition, and update parts).    This is "line 1".

The inner `for` statement will be executed once for every iteration of the outer loop.   The outer loop iterates `n` times, so the inner `for` statement is executed `n` times.  This is "line 2".

`"hi"` will be written once for every iteration of the inner loop.   The inner loop will iterate `n-i+1` times for each iteration of the outer loop (which produces the value of `i`).    That means the number of times `"hi"` is printed is is `n` (for `i == 1`) + `n-1` (for `i == 2`) + .... `1` (for `i==n`).   Adding them up, that equates to `n*(n+1)/2` times.    This is "line 3".

Comment: I'm supposed to include the initializer, condition and increments of the for loops. Since line 1 is executed only once, that should just be 1+(N+1)+1. For line two, since it's executed N times, would that mean the total steps would be N*(1+(N+1)+1) since the whole for loop resets for each N?

Comment: You're missing the fact that the variable that controls the outer loop also controls the number of iterations of the inner loop.